# Prevent HTML munging wordpress 4?

Tags: wordpress

I've looked into a Heap of plugins & ways to stop this from happening.

I want to be able to use wordpress visual editor without the editor changing my HTML at all. It removes  and other things.

I've tried TinyMCE advanced config & a few others.  Maybe this worked on wordpress 3 but I can't find something that works.

help!  this must be really simple!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The visual editor doesn't take HTML, it will always escape HTML chars so that you can display them to your users. In text mode you can paste in HTML which will work reasonably well, WordPress just tries to wrap paragraph tags around things, which is somewhat easy to prevent from happening.

Comment: This function is what I was talking about: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop. It gets run on WordPress content by default to add the paragraph tags. There is a plugin that will disable that for you if you really don't want WordPress to do that for you.

Comment: I just want to stop wordpress from changing my HTML when I edit it. I have latest version of wordpress , and I have tried wpautop but empty <em></em> tags are dissapearing. I really don't want anything to change. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Here is another question that has a summary of the problem you are seeing: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/147303/wordpress-visual-editor-stripping-html-changes

Comment: I'm thinking I maybe don't have Tiny MCE?  But I don't know how to find out what editor is being used.  Just because none of these seem to work , and debugging it says TinyMCE is not a valid object.  Ideas?